# Help with install Epiphany 3.3.4

Tags: compiling

When I compile from source, it gives me this after the "./configure" command.

[image: Dependency error]

I've already installed the "glib-2.0.0" that it initially told me it dependent on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you've got an old glib-2.0 and gio-unix-2.0 version installed.
try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install glib-2.0 gio-unix-2.0
```

After that you should logout and in again and try to configure again.

If that fails search for a new version and build the libraries from source when you cant find a new .deb package.

good luck ;)

btw: it would be much easier to read when you set your terminal to solid before making the screenshor or yust copy the text and paste it here.

Comment: did that, now Ubuntu won't even load. Thanks for the help anyways bro